# Does it make sense to mark variable as final in groovy?

Tags: optimization, groovy, final

I wonder how variables marked as *final* are interpreted by Groovy (in 1.8.0, 1.8.1). I know that it makes sense in Java and it is possible to improve the performance and -- of course -- help to avoid stupid mistakes. I would like to learn if *final* may help the java compiler to optimize a program written in Groovy. I wonder if Groovy transformers preserve the *final* markings for variables.

Comment: If you ask this [on the mailing list](http://xircles.codehaus.org/lists/user@groovy.codehaus.org), you're more likely to get a full answer...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [Justin has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177275/does-it-make-sense-to-mark-variable-as-final-in-groovy/7178802#7178802), if the optimisations that the compiler performs for final variables are important to you, then you shouldn't be using Groovy.

However, if the performance of Groovy is good enough, then it is still useful to mark variables final for two reasons:

- Protecting your class' invariants, i.e. making sure that a value cannot be changed after object construction. Java enforces this at compile-time, Groovy only enforces this at runtime, but this is better than silently allowing an immutable value to be changed
- Documentation. Users of your class can easily see which values they are allowed to change

Comment: The current version of Groovy (1.8.2) does not care about final and it does not enforce anything.

Comment: I've heard a lot of late about how groovy is starting to gain on performance. Does the above still reflect the picture as of Groovy 2.2 or versions on the roadmap?

Answer (score 19):

It doesn't appear that `groovyc` will inline final variables the way javac does. I created two test scripts, one using final and one not:

```
final String message = "Hello World"
println message
```

```
String message = "Hello World"
println message
```

`javap -c` produced the same output for both classes:

```
   0:   invokestatic    #18; //Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
   3:   astore_1
   4:   ldc #58; //String Hello World
   6:   astore_2
   7:   aload_1
   8:   ldc #59; //int 1
   10:  aaload
   11:  aload_0
   12:  aload_2
   13:  invokeinterface #63,  3; //InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callCurrent:(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   18:  areturn
   19:  nop
```

`javac` optimized away the `astore`/`aload`:

Without `final`:

```
   0:   ldc #2; //String Hello World
   2:   astore_1
   3:   getstatic   #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   6:   aload_1
   7:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   10:  return
```

With `final`:

```
   0:   getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3:   ldc #3; //String Hello World
   5:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   8:   return
```

All that said, if performance is paramount, Groovy is a poor choice to begin with. Inlining final variables won't save you from the overhead of using reflection for method calls.

Comment: Thx, regarding your last statement, I am aware of the fact that Groovy is much slower than Java or Scala.

Answer (score 4):

## Original post: Bug is open

not yet. but it might in a future, so I still mark them if appropriate.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1628

## Update post: Bug is "Fixed" in 2.5.x

[GROOVY-1628 - Inconsistent checking of final](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1628) has been marked as "Fixed" on 2015-03-13 with "Fix Version/s" set to "2.5.0-beta-1".