# Groovy Attribute should have type 'java.lang.Integer', but found type 'java.lang.Object'

Tags: groovy, annotations, junit4

I have the following JUnit test:

```
public class JavaTest {

    final int value = 2;

    @Test
    @Repeat(times = value)
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

The `@Repeat` annotation comes from [easytest-core](https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest-core), and the exact definition is [here](https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/easetech/easytest/annotation/Repeat.java).

When I compile this as java source everything builds (and runs) fine. When I compile the exact same thing as groovy source, I get:

> Groovy:Attribute 'times' should have type 'java.lang.Integer'; but found type 'java.lang.Object' in @org.easetech.easytest.annotation.Repeat  GroovyTest.groovy

After searching the internets, I found a few similar discussions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648398/using-value-spring-annotation-with-groovy) and [jira.codehaus](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3278), but those deal with String - GString problems, so the solutions do not work for me.

How can I fix this?

**Updates**:

- java.version=1.7.0_76
- groovy.version=2.3.7

Comment: Have you tried `final Integer` in place of `final int`?

Comment: @tim_yates I have now. :p Groovy reports the same problem. Java now reports "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to int".

Comment: where does it report that?  with the `final...` or with the `times=`?

Comment: @cfrick The error is on the `@Repeat(times = value)` line.

Comment: woudn't a `static` be here more approrivate anyway?

Comment: Just as an experiment you could try adding `@CompileStatic` to the class.

Comment: @cfrick No: "The value for annotation attribute Repeat.times must be a constant expression".

Comment: @cjstehno Still same problem. :(

Comment: i mean a `static final` and then using `JavaTest.value` to assign.

Comment: What version of Java and Groovy are you using?

Comment: @cjstehno Updated the OP with details: J=1.7 and G=2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you're bumping into the fact groovyc doesn't treat final variables as inline constants like javac does

I tried changing your int variable like this:

```
final Integer value = Integer.valueOf(2).intValue()
```

which prevents the variable from being treated as an inline constant. After that change I get a compile error from the `@Repeat` annotation:

> Expected Integer.valueOf(2).intValue() to be an inline constant

It looks like there's some acknowledgement of the inconsistency here in a Groovy JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1628

There's also some further discussion here in this SO thread:
[Does it make sense to mark variable as final in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177275/does-it-make-sense-to-mark-variable-as-final-in-groovy/7178802#7178802)

It doesn't look like you're going to be able to get groovy to match the Java behavior for this scenario.

Comment: Bummer. That jira ticket says *something* is fixed in version 2.5.0, but Maven Central says the last released is 2.4.3.